# How to handle selected rows from two different data tables in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using two different data tables in lightning.

1. On page load i am showing one data table.
2. In search bar on search of particular keyword,i am displaying another datatable to display the search results.

when search results is displayed the page load datatable wont appear.

Now the issue is i will select one particular record from on page datatable.

I will search some results and will select one record from second datatable also.

on selection of results from second datatable the first datatable selected records were clearing out.How to handle this scenerio?

### Component attributes:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedRowsDetails" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsList" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="maxRowSelection" type="Integer" default="25"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" />
```

### First data table i am using as below:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.searchResult)}">
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                     data="{!v.data}"
                     keyField="Id"
                     onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                     selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"                                                    
                     maxRowSelection="{!v.maxRowSelection}"
                     onrowselection="{!c.handleSelectedRow}"                                                                 
                     enableInfiniteLoading="true"
                     loadMoreOffset="{!v.loadMoreOffset}"
                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"                                                                
                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"                                                              
                     defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection }"
                     onsort="{!c.handleColumnSorting}"
                     onloadmore="{!c.handleLoadMoreAssets}"/>
</aura:if>
```

### second data table as below:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.searchResult))}">
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                     data="{!v.searchResult}"
                     keyField="Id"
                     onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                     selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"                                                    
                     maxRowSelection="{!v.maxRowSelection}"
                     onrowselection="{!c.handleSelectedRow}"                                                                 
                     enableInfiniteLoading="true"
                     loadMoreOffset="{!v.loadMoreOffset}"
                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"                                                                
                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"                                                              
                     defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection }"
                     onsort="{!c.handleColumnSorting}"
                     onloadmore="{!c.handleLoadMoreAssets}"/>
</aura:if>
```

### controller methods for the above tables:

```
    handleSelectedRows: function (component, event, helper) {
        var data = component.get('v.data');
        var selectedRowList =  component.get("v.selectedRowsList");
    },
handleSelectedRow: function(component, event, helper){
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        component.set("v.selectedRowsCount", selectedRows.length);
        let obj =[] ; 
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            obj.push({Name:selectedRows[i].Name});
            }
        component.set("v.selectedRowsDetails", JSON.stringify(obj) );
        component.set("v.selectedRowsList", event.getParam('selectedRows'));
        },
```

[image]

In the above screen shot added products from available datatable genwattdiesel100kw and added searched product SLA:Silver.In the same way i want to add the products from two datatables.

I wrote two different onrowselection functions,to handle two different datatable attributes.Now how to combile those two attributes into single attribute to get all the selected items.

Comment: Please include samples of the code you're running, such as the declarations of the data tables and your `onrowselection` handler. It sounds like you're just overwriting the data into the same attribute.

Comment: You need use the keyField to store the data as a session selected values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data tables are sharing virtually all of their bindings and action handlers:

```
                 onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                 selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"                                                    
                 maxRowSelection="{!v.maxRowSelection}"
                 onrowselection="{!c.handleSelectedRow}"                                                                 
                 loadMoreOffset="{!v.loadMoreOffset}"
                 sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"                                                                
                 sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"                                                              
                 defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection }"
                 onsort="{!c.handleColumnSorting}"
                 onloadmore="{!c.handleLoadMoreAssets}"
```

Your controller code doesn't look at *which* data table is the source of any given event, and instead populates the relevant data into a single component attribute:

```
    component.set("v.selectedRowsDetails", JSON.stringify(obj) );
    component.set("v.selectedRowsList", event.getParam('selectedRows'));
```

You will find that this code structure has a number of unexpected effects, including "smearing" of both selection and sorting data across your tables. I would anticipate your infinite loading to behave rather strangely too.

If your tables have data and action that's entirely independent of one another, you'll probably find it easiest to implement separate controller actions for the two tables. You'll certainly need separate attributes to act as backing stores for the table state, such as the sorting order and key and the current selected rows.

Comment: I want to select the records from both the tables.How can i achieve it? This functionality is same as adding products to an opportunity.

Comment: As I stated above, you will need to write controller logic that is tailored for each of the tables separately, and maintain their state in separate attributes.

Comment: I'd be happy to expand in a more specific answer, but I would suggest you start by trying to implement this functionality and come back to ask about a specific issue you encounter.

Comment: Created two different methods for two different tables and storing the values in two different attributes.Now how will all those come under single list.

Comment: component.set("v.secondselectedRowsDetails", JSON.stringify(secobj) );
component.set("v.secondselectedRowsList", event.getParam('selectedRows'));

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "single list". I would suggest that that *may* be a new question, but you'll need to be clearer about your objectives. This is one spot where screen shots may help alongside code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2 tables using only 1 data, assuming that you have posted your code here. Take note that  `onrowselection="{! c.rowSelectAction}"/>` will handle the actions upon row selection and will also affect the data from where your 2 tables are using. If you could just post your code here so that well see what the real problem is then I can help you more than just giving you tips.